# В чем смысл использования switch(1)?

Tags: c, инспекция-кода, switch

По основам программирования была дана задача на использование оператора `switch`, с его помощью написать программу, предлагающую на выбор пользователю два блюда или ничего на 4 типа блюд. Написал так:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <conio.h> 
#include <locale.h> 

int main() 
{ 
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus"); 
int a, b, c, d, obsh;  
printf("Что вы хотите на первое?\n1.Щи\n2.Борщ\n3.Ничего\n");
scanf("%i", &a); 
switch (a){ 
case 1: obsh = 150; 
break; 
case 2: obsh = 200; 
break; 
case 3: obsh = 0; 
break;
} 

printf("Что вы хотите на второе?\n1.Котлеты с макаронами\n2.Сосиски с пюре\n3.Ничего\n"); 
scanf("%i", &b); 
switch(b) { 
case 1: obsh += 200; 
break; 
case 2: obsh += 250; 
break; 
case 3: obsh += 0; 
break;
} 
printf("Что вы хотите на десерт?\n1.Творожную запеканку\n2.Блинчик\n3.Ничего\n"); 
scanf("%i", &c); 
switch (c){ 
case 1: obsh += 100; 
break; 
case 2: obsh += 75; 
break; 
case 3: obsh += 0; 
break;
} 

printf("Что вы хотите попить?\n1.Чай\n2.Компот\n3.Ничего\n");
scanf("%i", &d); 
switch(d){ 
case 1: obsh += 50; 
break; 
case 2: obsh += 30; 
break; 
case 3: obsh += 0; 
break;
} 


printf("Итого: %i", obsh); 

getch(); 
return 0; 
}
```

При этом данный вариант был рассмотрен как правильный, но кривой.
Идеальным же в итоге был такой:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <conio.h> 
#include <locale.h> 

int main() 
{ 
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus"); 
int a, b, c, d, obsh; 
switch(1){ 
case 1: 
printf("Что вы хотите на первое?\n1.Щи\n2.Борщ\n3.Ничего\n");
scanf("%i", &a); 
switch (a){ 
case 1: obsh = 150; 
break; 
case 2: obsh = 200; 
break; 
case 3: obsh = 0; 
} 

case 2: 
printf("Что вы хотите на второе?\n1.Котлеты с макаронами\n2.Сосиски с пюре\n3.Ничего\n"); 
scanf("%i", &b); 
switch(b) { 
case 1: obsh += 200; 
break; 
case 2: obsh += 250; 
break; 
case 3: obsh += 0; 
} 
case 3: 
printf("Что вы хотите на десерт?\n1.Творожную запеканку\n2.Блинчик\n3.Ничего\n"); 
scanf("%i", &c); 
switch (c){ 
case 1: obsh += 100; 
break; 
case 2: obsh += 75; 
break; 
case 3: obsh += 0; 
} 
case 4: 
printf("Что вы хотите попить?\n1.Чай\n2.Компот\n3.Ничего\n");
scanf("%i", &d); 
switch(d){ 
case 1: obsh += 50; 
break; 
case 2: obsh += 30; 
break; 
case 3: obsh += 0; 
} 
} 

printf("Итого: %i", obsh); 

getch(); 
return 0; 
}
```

Вопрос почему? В чем отличие и для чего использовать такой `switch`?

Comment: Единственное назначение которое я вижу - показать как работает switch с case-ами без break-ов, первый же кейс выполняется и по остальным идет сквозной проход до последнего.

Comment: Предположу что во втором варианте было показано два способа использования `switch`, с применением `break` и без.

Comment: `switch(1){ case 1:` и неявный провал в следующий `case` блок - это идиотизм...

Comment: Я бы тоже назвал кривым именнно второй вариант

Comment: (здесь, кстати, метка «инспекция кода» случайно не нужна?)

Comment: Идеолог пропустил метод дефаулт у свича, с ним можно было реализовать более красиво :)

Answer (score 1):

В логике отличий нет, писать как во втором варианте незачем и даже, более того, вредно. Единственно можно предположить, раз уж это учебный пример, что преподаватель оценил, что во втором варианте оператор `switch` применен двумя способами: с применением `break` и без. Обратите внимание, все вложенные `switch` используют оператор `break` для выходы из веток, а внешний `switch` не содержит `break`. Ветки внешнего `switch`  будут выполняться последовательно без переходов, что равносильно первому примеру.

В профессиональной разработке за такое надо на кол сажать, а лучше заставлять поддерживать это волшебство.

Comment: Единственное удивительное дело - первый вариант назван "кривым"))

Comment: @yolosora Если вам снизили оценку можете смело протестовать и покажите ссылку не это обсуждение. Но мне кажется что где-то в условиях к заданию всетаки было написани типо "использовать switch во всех вариантах" ;)

Comment: это не мой вопрос))

Answer (score 0):

Конструкции типа

```
switch (1)
{
  case 1:
  ...
}
```

иногда используются в качестве приемов реализации т.наз. "структурного goto", т.е. блока кода, на конец которого можно в любой момент передать управление при помощи `break`. В эту же категорию попадает и

```
do
{
  ...
} while (0);
```

(не путать с применением `do{}while(0)` внутри макросов).

Но в вашем "идеальном" варианте не видно ничего подобного и не видно никакой необходимости для чего-либо подобного. Наоборот, неоправданное применение внешнего `switch` в этом варианте - ужасно.

Comment: *"блока кода, на конец которого можно в любой момент передать управление при помощи `break`"* очень не хватает примера использования.

Comment: @älёxölüt, я так полагаю, имеется в виду что из такого блока можно выйти оператором `break`. Вот лично мне кажется, что если уж такое понадобилось, то лучше использовать `goto`, который для этого и предназначен. А не громоздить странные "структурные" конструкции. Это будет как минимум понятнее.